# ANTLR Grammar: reject if match other rule

Tags: antlr

Im beginner of antlr,
Im try to write an antlr grammar (.g4 file) for follow rules:

- Accept AND (&) between two variable: A&B, ABC&X, ...
- Accept Unicode string begin with U&'hex string': U&'000b', U&'0020', ...
- Accept concat string between variable (string type) and string: A&'123', ABC&'XyZ', ...

My question is how to reject concat string between **U&'XyZ'**? because **U&** is prefix of unicode string

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

`U&'XyZ'` should never be able to be recognised as a AND expression by the parser because `U&'XyZ'` is already tokenised as a single Unicode string token in the lexer:

```
expr
 : expr '&' expr
 | STRING
 | ID
 ;

STRING
 : 'U&'? '\'' ( ~[\\'\r\n] | '\\' ~[\r\n] )* '\''
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;
```

which will parse `U&'XyZ'&X` as this:

[image]